# How to pass a c++/CLI ref class as a function parameter

Tags: c++-cli, reference-class

I have a c++/CLI ref class called `LFSparams` in my visual c++ code.
I want to pass an object of this class as a function parameter:
(I get the LFSparameters object as a function parameter from c# code)

```
lfsparms actual_lfsparms = Convert2lfs(LFSparameters);
```

but VS says: "   "Nbis::LFSparams" has no suitable copy constructor"

The problem is, there is no way to create a copy constructor for a reference class, also I can not pass the object by reference, because it is already a reference.

So how can I pass this object as a parameter?

Comment: The bug is in the declaration of Convert2lfs.  We can't see it but surely you forgot to declare the argument with the ^ hat.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks!